# How do I detect multiple duplicate fields in a file using Perl?

Tags: perl, duplicates, field

I have a bunch of orders for NETFLIX in my brokerage account.
I inadvertently entered two duplicate gtc Sell orders on 1/5 and 1/6.
How do I detect it using a Perl script?

```
 Buy NFLX     50 @  315.00  Reg-Acct Fake
 Buy NFLX     50 @  317.50  Reg-Acct OPEN              01/13/15
Sell NFLX     50 @  345.00  Reg-Acct OPEN              01/05/15
Sell NFLX     50 @  345.00  Reg-Acct OPEN              01/06/15
Sell NFLX     50 @  362.00  Reg-Acct OPEN              11/25/14
...
Sell NFLX     50 @  345.00  IRA-Acct OPEN              09/15/14
```

I want the script to spit out just these two lines,
judged by `fields[0]` through `fields[6]` being identical.

```
Sell NFLX     50 @  345.00  Reg-Acct OPEN              01/05/15
Sell NFLX     50 @  345.00  Reg-Acct OPEN              01/06/15
```

I would prefer a simple script (i.e. no one-liner, no hash) as I am new to Perl.

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: You should probably point out which fields you are referring to, and if your data is fixed width, tab separated, space separated, etc.

Comment: The data is fixed width, space separated. The first seven fields are relevant (excluding the '@' of course) for judging duplication.  The date field is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said no one-liner, but in case you just meant no *perl* one-liners:

```
sort filename|rev|uniq -D -f 1|rev
```

Comment: `uniq: illegal option -- D
usage: uniq [-c | -d | -u] [-i] [-f fields] [-s chars] [input [output]]`

Comment: you need uniq from GNU coreutils; -D is like -d but prints all duplicate lines, not just the first of each set

Comment: I don't have rev and uniq on Windows (I have the GnuWin32 package.)  But your sort idea helped me presort the data and write a simple but inelegant script that works. I will be scanning here for more elegant implementations.

Comment: rev: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/util-linux-ng.htm uniq: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm

Comment: Perfect. Just rev and uniq work. What's the sort for? Thanks ysth.

Comment: uniq expects the input to be sorted; if you have a buy or a different sell between two duplicate sells, it won't find it unless you sort first.

Answer (score 0):

> I would prefer a simple script (no hash)

Ugh.  Missed the *no hash*.  Unfortunately, *simple* and *no hash* are opposing goals--not to mention *no hash* means *not efficient*, i.e. *slow*.  See code at bottom for how you should do it.  In the meantime, you'll need parallel arrays:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my @orders;
my @counts;

my $fname = 'data3.txt';

open my $ORDERSFILE, '<', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname: $!";

LINE:
while (my $line = <$ORDERSFILE>) {
    my @pieces = split ' ', $line;
    my $date = pop @pieces;
    my $order = join ' ', @pieces;

    if (not @orders) { #then length of @orders is 0
        $orders[0] = $order;
        $counts[0] = 1;
        next LINE;
    }

    for my $i (0..$#orders) {
        if ($orders[$i] eq $order) {
            $counts[$i]++;
            next LINE;
        }
    }
    #If execution reaches here, then the order wasn't found in the array...
    my $i = $#counts + 1;
    $orders[$i] = $order;
    $counts[$i] = 1
}

say Dumper(\@orders);
say Dumper(\@counts);


for my $i (0..$#counts) {
    if ($counts[$i] > 1) {
        say "($counts[$i]) $orders[$i]";
    }
}

--output:--
$VAR1 = [
          'Buy NFLX 50 @ 315.00 Reg-Acct',
          'Buy NFLX 50 @ 317.50 Reg-Acct OPEN',
          'Sell NFLX 50 @ 345.00 Reg-Acct OPEN',
          'Sell NFLX 50 @ 362.00 Reg-Acct OPEN',
          'Sell NFLX 50 @ 345.00 IRA-Acct OPEN'
        ];

$VAR1 = [
          1,
          1,
          2,
          1,
          1
        ];

(2) Sell NFLX 50 @ 345.00 Reg-Acct OPEN
```

Here are some better solutions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my %dates_for;   #A key will be an order; a value will be a reference to an array of dates.

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my @pieces = split ' ', $line;
    my $date = pop @pieces;
    my $order = join ' ', @pieces;

    push @{$dates_for{$order}}, $date;  #autovivification (see explanation below)
}

say Dumper(\%dates_for);

my @dates;

for my $order (keys %dates_for) {
    @dates = @{$dates_for{$order}};
    my $dup_count = @dates;

    if ($dup_count > 1) {
        say "($dup_count) $order";
        say "   $_" for @dates;
    }
}


__DATA__
 Buy NFLX     50 @  315.00  Reg-Acct Fake
 Buy NFLX     50 @  317.50  Reg-Acct OPEN              01/13/15
Sell NFLX     50 @  345.00  Reg-Acct OPEN              01/05/15
Sell NFLX     50 @  345.00  Reg-Acct OPEN              01/06/15
Sell NFLX     50 @  362.00  Reg-Acct OPEN              11/25/14
Sell NFLX     50 @  345.00  IRA-Acct OPEN              09/15/14  


--output:--
$VAR1 = {
          'Sell NFLX 50 @ 345.00 IRA-Acct OPEN' => [
                                                     '09/15/14'
                                                   ],
          'Sell NFLX 50 @ 345.00 Reg-Acct OPEN' => [
                                                     '01/05/15',
                                                     '01/06/15'
                                                   ],
          'Buy NFLX 50 @ 317.50 Reg-Acct OPEN' => [
                                                    '01/13/15'
                                                  ],
          'Buy NFLX 50 @ 315.00 Reg-Acct' => [
                                               'Fake'
                                             ],
          'Sell NFLX 50 @ 362.00 Reg-Acct OPEN' => [
                                                     '11/25/14'
                                                   ]
        };

(2) Sell NFLX 50 @ 345.00 Reg-Acct OPEN
   01/05/15
   01/06/15
```

> When an undefined variable is dereferenced, it gets silently upgraded
>   to an array or hash reference (depending of the type of the
>   dereferencing). This behaviour is called autovivification and usually
>   does what you mean (e.g. when you store a value)....

http://search.cpan.org/~vpit/autovivification-0.14/lib/autovivification.pm

For fixed width columns, it's more efficient to use unpack():

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fname = 'data3.txt';

open my $ORDERSFILE, '<', $fname
    or die "Couldn't open $fname: $!";

my %dates_for;

while (my $line = <$ORDERSFILE>) {
    my ($order, $date) = unpack 'A41 @55 A*', $line;   #see explanation below
    push @{$dates_for{$order}}, $date;
}

close $ORDERSFILE;

say Dumper(\%dates_for);

my @dates;

for my $order (keys %dates_for) {
    @dates = @{$dates_for{$order}};

    if (@dates > 1) {
        my $dup_count = @dates;
        say "($dup_count) $order";
        say "   $_" for @dates;
    }
}

--output:--
$VAR1 = {
          ' Buy NFLX     50 @  317.50  Reg-Acct OPEN' => [
                                                           '01/13/15'
                                                         ],
          'Sell NFLX     50 @  362.00  Reg-Acct OPEN' => [
                                                           '11/25/14'
                                                         ],
          'Sell NFLX     50 @  345.00  Reg-Acct OPEN' => [
                                                           '01/05/15',
                                                           '01/06/15'
                                                         ],
          ' Buy NFLX     50 @  315.00  Reg-Acct Fake' => [
                                                           ''
                                                         ],
          'Sell NFLX     50 @  345.00  IRA-Acct OPEN' => [
                                                           '09/15/14'
                                                         ]
        };

(2) Sell NFLX     50 @  345.00  Reg-Acct OPEN
   01/05/15
   01/06/15
```

`A41 @55 A*` => extract 41 characters(A),
..............................skip to position 55(@55),
..............................extract the remaining characters(A*)

You can skip to any position you want, forwards and backwards, which means you can extract pieces in any order you want.